# Parse string with date and timezone to UTC datetime

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.x, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

I'm coding a Python 3 script that receives a full date with offset and I want to be able to compare it to another date without offset. The main problem I'm facing is that Python doesn't seem to like different offset datetime objects as it complains when you try to do any operation with those:

```
>>> date_string
'Wed, 8 May 2013 15:33:29 +0200'
>>> new_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
>>> new_date
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 8, 15, 33, 29, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0, 7200)))
>>> new_date - datetime.today()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

As a workaround I've stripped `date_string` into two strings, once with the date and one with the offset, creating two objects: one date and one delta, them sum them up:

```
>>> date_string
'Wed, 8 May 2013 15:33:29 +0200'
>>> match = re.match(r'(.*)(\s\+\d{4})',date_string)
>>> match.group(1)
'Wed, 8 May 2013 15:33:29'
>>> match.group(2)
' +0200'
>>> parsed_date = datetime.strptime(match.group(1), '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S')
>>> match_delta = re.match(r'\s\+(\d{2})(\d{2})',match.group(2))
>>> parsed_date_delta = timedelta(minutes=int(match_delta.group(2)),hours=int(match_delta.group(1)))
>>> parsed_date_complete = parsed_date + parsed_date_delta
>>> parsed_date_complete
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 8, 17, 33, 29)
```

With this I'm able to get a final hour with the correct offset applied, so any comparision with another normal datetime object wouldn't raise an error.

The thing I'm wondering is if there's an easier or more efficient way of achieving this. The idea is to receive a string like this one: `Wed, 8 May 2013 15:33:29 +0200` and be able to convert it in a datetime object without offset, so I can work with UTC times.

EDIT: To explain a little more the issue, `new_date` has an offset value of `+0200` while `datetime.today()` and `datetime.utcnow()` doesn't have that offset, so trying to compare it or do any operation gives the following error in Python: `TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`.

If date is `Wed, 8 May 2013 15:33:29 +0200`, what I want is a way to calculate date like this: `Wed, 8 May 2013 17:33:29`, without the offset value but with the right time (offset applied to time). That way, since I don't have the offset, I can freely do stuff with `datetime.today()` and `datetime.utcnow()`

Comment: you can look into this link for more .. http://emilics.com/blog/article/python_time.html

Comment: That link tells how to change formats, but if I reformat a datetime getting only the date (without the offset), I get a wrong date, since the hour wouldn't be the right one due to the offset.

Comment: My bad, I understood your question wrongly. letme try out somethign and comeback

Comment: Perhaps give my project here a try. Timestring seems like it can help you with tis problem... https://github.com/stevepeak/timestring there is offset features in the timestring project. Just not fully documented yet. Thanks!!

Comment: @StevePeak: Thanks for the tip, but I would like to achieve that without using any library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no python guru, but according to [these docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html):

> *classmethod* `datetime.today()`
>
> Return the current local datetime, with `tzinfo` None. ...

There is no time zone associated with the return value.  It's not at UTC, the offset is just unspecified.  It therefore makes sense that it wouldn't allow you to compare the two.  The result would be meaningless.

In other words, what would you expect the result of this to be?

```
10 May 2013 13:00 +0200  >  10 May 2013 12:00
```

- It *could* be true, because `13:00` is a greater *value* than `12:00`.
- It *could* be false, because maybe the local time zone offset is `-0100`, so you are comparing the moments `11:00Z  > 13:00Z`.  But who knows if we even meant to use the local offset since we didn't specify.

Since we are referring to an exact moment on the left side, but an ambiguous one on the right, the operation gives an error.

It's good that Python gives an error when you try to do this.  Other frameworks such as .Net make some assumptions and return results that might not be what you were expecting. ([Read here](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) if you are interested.)

So going back to your question, you said:

> The idea is to receive a string like this one: Wed, 8 May 2013 15:33:29 +0200 and be able to convert it in a datetime object without offset, so I can work with UTC times.

The string you have is already reflecting its offset from UTC.  The way you are parsing it is just fine.  You just need to compare it to something that is more meaningful, such as `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`

Comment: Sorry, I think I explained wrong in my question (I will update it right now). The thing is that `datetime.today()` and `datetime.utcnow()` doesn't have an offset, so if I try to use the `new_date`, I get the error: `TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`. The idea is to convert the `new_date` to the equivalent without offset, so it can be used with `datetime.utcnow()` and `datetime.today()`

Comment: @Peter - My mistake, looking closer at [the docs for utcnow()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) it says that it returns a naive datetime, rather than a timezone aware one.  Use `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` instead.  My point still stands - don't try to strip the offset away and compare naively, just make sure what you are comparing to is timezone aware.

Comment: That did it, using `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` with the `new_date` lets you do things with both using UTC.